# Handling Llong BLOBS and generating a random image

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, blob, encode

Using Python to make a photography website. I built the following function to generate a random image from my Table of images in mYSQL. Here is the function It seems like my image is being processed as a string after it is returned from the database, and I cannot figure out why. Would someone mind helping me? I am using Python Flask library, and SQL alchemy as an ORM

```
def generateRandomPhotoObject():

    # Query photo table for all entries
    obj = Photo.query.all()
    if len(obj) == 0:
        return
    # Choose a random entry from the table
    randomNumber = random.randint(0, len(obj) - 1)
    randomPhotoObject = obj[randomNumber]
    tempImage = randomPhotoObject.image
    tempImage = b64encode(tempImage).decode("utf-8")
    randomPhotoObject.image = tempImage
    return randomPhotoObject
```

This function runs and gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: What does your table of images contain? If it contains image names 'strings' then this is what you get. What IDE are you using? why not try to debug your code?

Comment: Using VSCode, The images are in the database as Long BLOBS and when i check their type in python it is 'bytes'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I arrived at a solution. I simply checked if the type is a string, then encoded it accordingly.

```
def generateRandomPhotoObject():

    # Query photo table for all entries
    obj = Photo.query.all()
    if len(obj) == 0:
        return
    # Choose a random entry from the table
    randomNumber = random.randint(0, len(obj) - 1)
    randomPhotoObject = obj[randomNumber]
    if type(randomPhotoObject.image) == str:
        tempImage = bytes(randomPhotoObject.image, encoding='utf-8')
    else:
        tempImage = b64encode(randomPhotoObject.image)
    tempImage = tempImage.decode("utf-8")
    randomPhotoObject.image = tempImage
    return randomPhotoObject
```